# Perl script in Crontab didn't move a file overnight

Tags: linux, perl

I have a script that might take a while to execute. It is executed once every minute. It has always worked:

```
while ( my $file = readdir $dir ) {

    next if (
           $file eq "."
        or $file eq ".."
        or $file eq ".bashrc"
        or $file eq ".bash_logout"
        or $file eq ".bash_profile" );

    my ( $ext ) = $file =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;

    if ( $ext eq ".pdf" ) {

        my $from = $print_direction . "/" . "$file";

        move( $from, $PDF_direction );

        my ( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) = localtime( time );
        $year = $year + 1900;
        $mon++;

        my $date       = "$year-$mon-$mday $hour:$min:$sec \n";
        my $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO registerPDF (id, file_name, created_at) VALUES (  '$id'  ,  '$file' , '$date')";
        my $insert_sth = $dbh->prepare( $insert_sql );
        $insert_sth->execute();

        chmod 0755, $PDF_direction . "/" . "$file";
        chown 48, 48, $PDF_direction . "/" . "$file";
    }
```

This has worked just fine for months.

I have recently added another Crontab script that reboots the server

```
system("reboot");
```

Yesterday a file was moved where they were supposed to but its entry was never found in the Database.

I am afraid this was caused by the system reboot which was triggered after a big file was being moved. Logs show nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to show your whole program.

Comment: the `if ( $ext eq ".pdf" ) {` will warn if the file has not any extension, e.g. if the `my ( $ext ) = $file =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;` will not match..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The file had this weird PhantomPDF format so even though it could be open with PDF viewers the format was not actually the same, so it never moved.

Comment: So, this is an extremely localized problem which is not due to anything in your Perl code. You should delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, aside from a crontab reboot being a bit on the filthy side - the major thing that tends to break with "readdir" type operations like this, is that you're not adding `$dir` to any of the subsequent modifications. So it could be you're *reading* a different `$dir` to your current working directory.

But the other possiblity is that your reboot meant that some transient state wasn't present, or the script was aborted part way, or maybe the database wasn't running as your script doesn't check return codes. If it "runs once a minute" and "takes a while" then it's *very* likely that a reboot will interrupt it.

Mostly I'm guessing, because a lot of the things you're asking about aren't contained within your script, so it's not a reproducible problem.

However, I'll also point out a few things:

- `readdir` has `$dir` specified, but `move` doesn't. Is there any chance that `$print_direction` doesn't match `$dir`?
- you `opendir` then reject a bunch of stuff, looking for `.pdf`. Why not instead: `foreach my $file ( glob "$dir/*.pdf" ) {` because that has the path built in.
- Rather than massaging `localtime` like that, have you considered using `Time::Piece`: `my $date_str = localtime -> strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");`
- you don't check any return codes. If the server rebooted, it's quite possible that the database wasn't actually running at the time the `move` ran, especially if it happens every minute.

Comment: The reboot happens once at 03:00 AM not every minute that'd be bad. Also there is nothing more to show in the script - other than a script to get all files recursively.

Comment: No, but if your _other_ script _starts_ running at 0300, and then the reboot happens in the middle, that'd do the same thing, right? Might want to check the 'moved' file is actually complete, because it might not have finished with the `mv` operation properly either.

Comment: *"Is there any chance that `$print_direction` doesn't match `$dir`?"* But `$print_direction` is presumably a path string while `$dir` is a directory handle. Likewise `foreach my $file ( glob "$dir/*.pdf" ) {` is wrong with a directory handle.